# A small error in my mdx query

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

```
    SCOPE([Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1].MEMBERS, [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah     GVV].[Task Sub Status].&[1].MEMBERS);
    THIS =[Measures].[Maximum Insertion DT];
    END SCOPE;
```

The above query generates an error ("the syntax for scope is incorrect")

What im trying to do: I want to display the max insertionid only for the pair of values of status=1 and substatus=1. In the cube all the status and substatus values show but i want the calculation to be only for those (1,1 as mentioned). Is that the right way to go about it?
Maximum Insertion ID, is a measure i created to return the max insertionid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others to benefit: the scope keyword cannot be used in the expression for a calculated measure. Instead I used and Case statement (could have used IIF but i caused problems for me in some cases). The case statement would be like case when status and substatus =1 then do call the max measure.

Comment: `SCOPE` is a ***statement***. Actually, when using `SCOPE`, you use at least three statements: `SCOPE`, one or more assignments, 'END SCOPE'. And a calculated measure definition requires an ***expression***. `SCOPE` can only be used in the calculation script of the cube, never in a `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 1):

What is [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1].MEMBERS assumed to mean? [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1] is a member already. Thus,

```
SCOPE({([Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1],
        [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Sub Status].&[1])
     });
    THIS =[Measures].[Maximum Insertion DT];
END SCOPE;
```

should work.

Comment: Frank I still get the same error though.. and [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1].MEMBERS was assumed to be the status 1 but yah its already a member so makes sense not to include the .members

Comment: @user1270078 Error messages normally contain row **and column**. Where in the scope does the error occur?

Comment: Thank you for the response Frank however I realized that the scope keyword cannot be used in the calculated measure and switched to an iif statement!